# Number of pages on SSRS Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that has more than 100 pages. When the report loads, by default it should show the actual number of pages but it shows 1 of 2 and the upper limit increases by 1 as we navigate to the next page. Do we need to change the settings to show the exact number of pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a pagebreak on your group? Check the properties on your tablix member by highlighting the row group name on the bottome panel and hitting F4. This should bring up the Tablix Member Properties windows, in which under the "Group" settings you can check and see if there is a pagebreak under the "PageBreak" options.  If one exists verify that Reset Page Number Is set to "False"

Hope this helps,

Cheers!

Comment: The Reset Page Number is already set as False but the page number is still not correctly reflecting on the report manager.

Comment: How many groups do you have? And did you check it for each group?

Comment: I don't have any group, only the header row and details row is there.